# Laravel middleware returning 405 when using ajax

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm logged into my website and the page I'm currently on requires the `admin` middleware.  I've also got an api call I'm making from this page.  This api call is also going through the same `admin` middleware and is in the `api.php` file (laravel 5.3).  My requests to the web page works.  However my middleware on the api call returns a 302 redirecting me to the `login` page.  My test case for this api call with `Auth::actingas($user)` works fine as well.  The middleware  does not seem to recognize that I am logged in even though the page does.

I've also added `api/*` to the exceptions list in `VerifyCSRF`.  How can I fix this?

Here's my `routes/web.php` file (the page I'm currently on is `manageAdmins`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['admin']], function(){
  Route::get('/', 'AdminController@showHome');
  Route::get('categories', 'AdminController@showCategories');
  Route::get('categories/add', 'AdminController@getAddCategories');
  Route::get('manageAdmins', 'AdminController@manageAdmins');

});
```

My `routes/api.php` file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');

Route::get('categories/{id}/children', 'CategoryController@getChildren');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['web', 'admin']], function() {
    Route::put('makeNormalUserOfAdmin/{id}', 'AdminController@makeNormalUserOfAdmin');
});
```

Here's the api call the admin middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard=null)
    {
        if (!(Auth::guard($guard)->check())) {
          return redirect('/login');
        }
        if(!(Auth::user()->is_admin)){
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Here is the api call that's failing:

```
/**
 * delete an admin from the database
 */
function deleteAdmin(id){
    $.ajax({
        method: "PUT",
        url: "/api/admin/makeNormalUserOfAdmin/" + id,
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("table#admins tr#id" + id).fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

and Finally here is the test case that is passing:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use App\User;

class MakeNormalUserOfAdminTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * Test the get categories method
     *
     *
     */
    public function testMakeNormalUserOfAdmin()
    {

        $miscalaneousUsers = factory(App\User::class, 20)->create();

        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create([
            'is_admin' => true
        ]);

        $this->actingAs($user)
            ->json("PUT", "api/admin/makeNormalUserOfAdmin/$user->id")
            ->assertResponseOk()
            ->assertResponseStatus(200);

        $this->seeInDatabase('users', [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'password' => $user->password,
            'remember_token' => $user->remember_token,
            'updated_at' => $user->updated_at,
            'created_at' => $user->created_at,
            'is_admin' =>  0
        ]);

        $this->dontSeeInDatabase('users', [
            'is_admin' => 1
        ]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not handle PUT requests, so laravel mimics it by sending POST with `_method=put` body field. So, in order for your request to work you need to add data

```
data: {
    _token: csrfToken,
    _method: 'put'
}
```

And change request method to POST

Comment: No idea to be fair :/